# Assigning an object/method to a variable OR a new object literal

Tags: object, variable-assignment, javascript

Looking at Google's code for their bookmark bubble library, I came across this:

```
var google = google || {};
google.bookmarkbubble = google.bookmarkbubble || {};
```

Could someone explain what it is they're doing here and why they are doing it? Since JS is an interpreted language why would you ever need to assign the same google object into the google variable? Wouldn't the script this is contained in only get executed once each time a page is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are setting up a namespace-like object.  In case there is already a `google` object or `google.bookmarkbubble` object, they are making sure they don't replace it.  For example, if you had another Google library added, it may have already set up a `google` object that looks like this:

```
{
    somelibrary: {
        ...
    }
}
```

So if they just had:

```
var google = { bookmarkbubble: { ... } }
```

That would break any code that referenced `google.somelibrary`.  Likewise, if they didn't have `var google = google || {};` and you didn't have `google` already defined, then `google.bookmarkbubble` would throw an error.

In short, this code ensures that a `google.bookmarkbubble` object exists without overwriting any previously-defined `google` or `google.bookmarkbubble` objects.

Comment: Could they be checking because they might have other libraries I'd be using that has the same google object? I never thought of that scenario.

Comment: Yes, that's probably exactly the reason.

Answer (score 1):

`var google = google || {};` is a shorthand syntax for

```
if (!google) {
  google = {};
}
```

This ensures that the second assignment doesn't fail because `google` is at a least an empty hash.

Comment: Do you happen to know if the var google = google || {}; shorthand syntax is only applicable to JavaScript?

Comment: In Ruby there's a dedicated operator for that: `google ||= {}`

Comment: @Aaron, I don't know if there are other languages that allow for the exact same code, but it's a common pattern in many languages.  In C#, for example, you'll often see `foo = foo ?? new Foo()` or in C++, this code would work if `foo` was a `Foo*` (and if it was initialized to null) `foo = foo || new Foo()`.

Comment: Awesome, glad to know some other languages support that kind of syntax!

Comment: I just tried that C++ example and saw "foo.cpp(9) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'bool' to 'Foo *'"

Answer (score 0):

This is most often done when one library contains a number of files which may or may not be included by the user. The first library will initialize `google` to an empty object (because it evaluates to nothing) and subsequent libraries will preserve properties already added to the object.